# Need help in enqueue data into Redis queue From Go consumer

Tags: go, redis, enqueue

I am trying to push data in redis queue from my Go Consumer.

The package I am using is **"github.com/kavu/go-resque"**

The redis Driver I am using is **"github.com/kavu/go-resque/go-redis"** and **"github.com/go-redis/redis"**

My code looks like this :

```
"github.com/kavu/go-resque"
_"github.com/kavu/go-resque/go-redis"
"github.com/go-redis/redis"
 "time"
 "strings"


 redisClient := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
    Addr:        myRedisIp,
    Password:    "", // no password set
    DB:          0,  // use default DB
    DialTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
})


  enqueuer := resque.NewRedisEnqueuer("go-redis", redisClient,"test-redis") 
_, err := enqueuer.Enqueue("resque:queue:myQueueName", "Demo::Job", 1, 2, "test")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("putting into queue failed error="+err.Error())
  }else{
     fmt.Println("putting into queue success")
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to implement this. Sharing steps :

1. **Install Packages**
   Resque Package  : `"github.com/kavu/go-resque"`
   Also, install the driver package i.e. redis package you want the resque to use. 
   There are multiple options for that eg: Go-redis, Godis, hoisie,redisGo etc
   In my case, I was am **Go-Redis**.
   So, I installed

   `"github.com/kavu/go-resque/go-redis"`

   `"github.com/go-redis/redis"`
2. **Then set Up the redis Client**

   `rc := redisQueue.New("Your redis server IP")`
3. Set Up resque struct

   `enqueuer := resque.NewRedisEnqueuer("redis-go", rc,"resque:")`

Here, first parameter is driver name like godis,redis-go etc. Second parameter is redis Client i.e. Go-redis client or godis client etc. Third parameter is namespace. That is what you want to append in your queueName.

4. Then enqueue the packet into queue

   `NumPacketsInQueue, err = enqueuer.Enqueue(queueName,"",args1,args2...)`

The second empty parameter in above code line is job Class.I have kept it empty.

Here, the final queuename will be resque:queue:queueName

**Links:**

1. [github.com/kavu/go-resque](https://godoc.org/github.com/kavu/go-resque)
2. https://github.com/kavu/go-resque/blob/master/go-redis/driver.go
3. [Godis and Go Resque](https://libraries.io/go/github.com%2Fkavu%2Fgo-resque)